# Icons don't appear after build when opening on other computer

Tags: java

I was working with JFrame in Netbeans, Java. I've made some buttons and added icons to them. When I build my project and open .jar file on my computer, I see the icons, but if I open that file on other computer, those buttons are empty. Where should I put the icons, so I could see them on another computer after build?

Comment: Put them into your jar file and address/load them through class resources. SomeClazz.class.getResource("relativePath").

Answer (score 1):

They should be inside your jar file, and loaded as resources.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. What I had to do is to put those icons into my projects package folder, then select "Image within project" in button options and add them again.